# Java Streaming Image or Video Over HTTP

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming

I am developing application with Java and Opencv. I want to view the my processing image or video from via web browser. I am creating images dynamically, there is no video in the file system. How can I do that. Which protocol or library should I use?

Example

```
VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
while(videoCapture.read(frame)) {
/*-frame is matris array or BufferedImage
  -image processing on image */

//I want to display this image(frame) on browser (streaming)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Source code https://github.com/mesutpiskin/HTTPLiveStreamFromOpenCV

Comment: Can you give some code snippet on how to display the stream from your `HttpStreamServer` in the browser?

Comment: yeah sure https://github.com/mesutpiskin/opencv-live-video-stream-over-http/blob/1d3a449df0e5337a3956f9dc5df91c9520137b7e/src/main/java/HttpStreamServer.java#L46